# mysql_fetch_array() always return null

Tags: php, mysql

I am try to fetch data from the database

```
$check_sql = 'SELECT * FROM table;
$check_result = mysql_query($check_sql);
echo $check_result;
$result = mysql_fetch_array($check_result);
```

when I `echo $check_result`, it shows 'Resource id 2', which i think it means there exists a return array, but when I use `mysql_fetch_array`, it will return a null value, and I don't know why...
And I found that no matter whether there exists the resules or not, `echo $check_result` would always shows 'Resource id#2', does this sentence in mysql mean 'no results' ? Could someone help???

Comment: Did you try to use `mysql_error()`? http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php There might be an output.

Comment: The `mysql_` functions [are deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php); please don't use them in new code.  Use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) instead.

Comment: @JonasSchwabe when I tried 'mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nonexistenttable", $link);', it said ' mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource'

Comment: @BradKoch but I've been using it all these days, and never got this error before

Comment: Deprecated means that they will be removed in further versions of PHP so if you are starting now you should definitely have a look at the other techniques (PDO / MySQLi). Regarding the other comment, are you sure $link is a MySQL-Link? Maybe you override it somewhere before?

Comment: @JonasSchwabe I used a wrong field name!!! That why it always null! I spend an hour on this stupid problem, Now it works, thanks! But why it still returns 'resource id#2', I thought this means there is actually something in the results...

Comment: You will always get a resource, even if the query is wrong. #2 is only the id, if you echo the next query you do you will get #3 or similar (at least something else than 2)

Comment: mysql_fetch_array returns either an `array` or `false`, never `null`.

Answer (score -1):

`mysql_fetch_array()` returns an array.
You definitely must take a look at documentation http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array

Try `print_r($result);`

Answer (score -1):

In case if you are dealing with multiple rows in your mysql query you need to use code like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($check_result) )
{
   echo $row['ROW_NAME_HERE'];
}
```

I guess it is why you mentioned mysql_fetch_array function.

Comment: I use 'LIMIT 1' in my query,so there should be only one row in the result

Comment: then try to `print_r($check_result);`

Comment: @jan267 it still only print 'Resource id #2'

Comment: Yeah, sure, try with `print_r($result);`. `$check_result` is only a query resource!